# How modify and use totals in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have several measures names and 5 dates and I need to create a calculated field over the first 4 dates and use the result in news calculated fields with the 5 date

```
          date1      date2       date3    date4     date5   AVGdate1-4
```

measure1
measure2
.
.
measureN

Comment: Are you able to share a sample workbook? I'm afraid it's not clear from your post what you are trying to achieve. I assume your measures are all numbers? If so, are you looking to sum all the values that occur on dates 1 through to 4?

Comment: I can't share the book but its this :

I have a Calculated field (J)  that is the result of the sum of two fields
J = sum(A) = sum(B)
now I need to find
AVG(J)
but I cant :
"argument to AVG(an aggregate function) is already an aggregation, cannot be further aggregated"
pls help I'm new using tableau.

Comment: You should be able to right click on the J pill and change the aggregation to Average in your worksheet, rather than having to edit the calculation.